What's the explanation of the proof for how we know all synagogues will become uprooted from the ground to go to Eretz Yisroel?
B"H
Megillah 29a with commentators says that in the future time, all synagogues will become uprooted from their places throughout the world and collectively fly in the air to travel to the land of Yisroel, to unite with the future Third Temple.
The kal vachomer proof it brings is that by the revelation at Mount Sinai, a few other mountains became uprooted from their places to go to the mountain, in order for Hashem to give the Torah on them instead.
The gemara says that if even a few words of Torah that were spoken at Mount Sinai were enough to cause even mountains to become uprooted from their places, how much more so when it comes to synagogues and houses of Torah study, which constantly have words of Torah said in them.
But what exactly is the proof? In the case of the mountains, the reason why they became uprooted was in the hopes that the Torah would be given on them, but the synagogues already have words of Torah being said in them, so what does the words of Torah being said in them have to do with them being uprooted?
Language from the source in question:

תַּנְיָא, רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר הַקַּפָּר אוֹמֵר: עֲתִידִין בָּתֵּי
כְנֵסִיּוֹת וּבָתֵּי מִדְרָשׁוֹת שֶׁבְּבָבֶל שֶׁיִּקָּבְעוּ בְּאֶרֶץ
יִשְׂרָאֵל, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״כִּי כְּתָבוֹר בֶּהָרִים וּכְכַרְמֶל בַּיָּם
יָבֹא״, וַהֲלֹא דְּבָרִים קַל וָחוֹמֶר: וּמָה תָּבוֹר וְכַרְמֶל
שֶׁלֹּא בָּאוּ אֶלָּא לְפִי שָׁעָה לִלְמוֹד תּוֹרָה, נִקְבָּעִים
בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל, בָּתֵּי כְנֵסִיּוֹת וּבָתֵּי מִדְרָשׁוֹת
שֶׁקּוֹרִין וּמַרְבִּיצִין בָּהֶן תּוֹרָה — עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה
וְכַמָּה.
It is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Elazar HaKappar says: In the future,
the synagogues and the study halls in Babylonia will be transported
and reestablished in Eretz Yisrael, as it is stated: “Surely, like
Tabor among the mountains, and like Carmel by the sea, so shall he
come” (Jeremiah 46:18). There is a tradition that these mountains came
to Sinai at the giving of the Torah and demanded that the Torah should
be given upon them. And are these matters not inferred through an a
fortiori argument: Just as Tabor and Carmel, which came only
momentarily to study Torah, were relocated and established in Eretz
Yisrael in reward for their actions, all the more so should the
synagogues and study halls in Babylonia, in which the Torah is read
and disseminated, be relocated to Eretz Yisrael.
רש"י וככרמל בים יבא: למדנו שעבר כרמל את הים ואימתי היה בשעת מתן תורה:


It’s an interesting question that’s dependent on perspective. If you view the relocation to Eretz Israel as the “uprooting” then it makes sense. I.e just like the mountains came and only “momentarily studied Torah” got rewarded with getting uprooted to Israel, all the more so  synagogues who constantly have Torah studied should get rewarded with getting uprooted to Israel
Look at it as a reward for studying Torah being the reason they got uprooted to Israel and not that they only got uprooted in order to learn Torah
Based on the way you phrased your question it seems like your viewing the uprooting to Har Sinai in which case yes your logic would stand correct as to how the kal vachomer works, but for this reason (and also mainly that we are talking about uprooting to Israel) I think that you must view it in the other way as I have explained and then the kal vachomer works quite nicely

The gemara is saying the mountains were uprooted from Mount Sinai to Israel? Were they always at Mount Sinai before that?

See Rashi there who says “we learned that Carmel moved over the sea…”. Seems to be that originally they were not originally at Sinai, they transported there in hopes for the Torah to be transmitted on them, and even though it didn’t, they nonetheless got rewarded for the little Torah that they learned that they got uprooted to Israel

Oh, so they were uprooted TWO times. I guess that's what confused me, the proof from the gemara is only from the second time, but not the first? But then what does being uprooted and going to Israel have to do with having words of Torah said on them? The first time makes sense, because they were uprooted in order to have Torah said on them, but the second time, it just happened, because...?

Yes exactly, the explicit proof from the Gemara is the second time, the first time is what we learn from Midrash/commentators that they came in hopes of getting the Torah given on them. So the first time they were uprooted was in order for the Torah to be given on them. The second time, and this is from where the Gmara learns about Synagogues getting uprooted, is solely because of the merit they had that while they were already in Sinai they heard some words of Torah…so obviously all the more so for Synagogues whom constantly hear words of Torah will also get uprooted to Israel

Ah I see. But what does going to Israel have to do with having words of Torah said on them? What's the connection?

It’s a zchut (merit) to be in Israel. If Hashem had destined for these mountains originally to be outside of Israel, now because they learned a little bit of Torah they got  rewarded to be in the holy land. We basically learn from here the merit of learning even a little bit of Torah as well as the chashivut (importance) of being in Israel
